# Matrix Optimisation methods

Tags: math, matrix, linear-algebra, mathematical-optimization

I want to perform optimisation to get the appropriate values of the transformation matrix R.

A = R*B

where:
A = [x2,y2,1]
B = [x1,y1,1]

And R is the 3x3 transformation matrix I need to find. What is the best optimisation method or any optimisation method that can help me solve for 3 x 3 Matrix R.

Note A and B are elements are scalar.

Comment: this is not really a programming question

Comment: i think thats why i tagged Math and linear algebra. Maybe for your information maths and programming are very closely related.

Comment: you should post it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The Lagrange functional for the task to find a minimal R such that A=RB is

> L(R,U)=0.5 * |R|^2 + U<sup>T</sup> * (A - R * B)

with R-derivative

> 0=dL/dR = R<sup>T</sup> - B * U<sup>T</sup>.

Reinserting the resulting form

> R = U * B<sup>T</sup>

into the condition yields

> A = U * B<sup>T</sup> * B = U * |B|^2

so that finally

> R = A * B<sup>T</sup>/|B|^2,

which is probably not what you were looking for, since it has rank 1 and not rank 3. So please care to refine your expectations on what makes an optimal transformation matrix.